# Are there situations where a vertical bar chart is preferable to a horizontal one?

Tags: data-visualization, references, barplot

I hardly see what kind of advantage a vertical bar chart could have over a horizontal one (edit: by "horizontal bar chart", I mean a chart with bars oriented horizontally). On the other hand, vertical bar charts are so prevailing that it makes me wonder if I'm just lacking imagination or experience.

[image]

In particular, I'm wondering:

- If you have many categories to plot, the labels for each category on a horizontal bar chart are easier to read (e.g. you don't have to move your head to read a vertical or rotated label). Are there situations where this isn't true?
- If you have long labels for the categories, an horizontal bar chart requires less line breaks than a vertical bar chart. Thus, a horizontal bar plot is probably easier to read. Again, are there situations where this isn't true?

These are two examples where horizontal bar charts are likely superior, but maybe there are other situations I'm not thinking of, and where vertical bar plots have an advantage. I'd be interested to learn about that. (This [blog post](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2021/04/12/horizontal-bar-chart.html) talks about the issue, if you're interested in some visual examples and my previous examples are not clear - note that I'm not a SAS user, by the way).

A practical stake for me is work-related, i.e. automation of graph generation. Recently I've been wondering if I should make horizontal bar charts the default (as it's easier to deal with labels overlap and so on, it would save me some programming time). On the other hand, I don't want to generate incorrect or misleading data visualizations, or run into other problems I did not anticipate. Hence my question.

I'm definitely not looking for answers similar to "I find vertical bars ugly" or other opinion-based answers. I'm looking for practical, objective issues that members of an audience may encounter with horizontal bar charts, but not with vertical bars. Which makes me think that I'd also be interested in references on the subject - peer-reviewed publications based on experiments would be perfect.

Edit:

I realize that my question assumes we're dealing with graphs in English or other languages where vertical writing is not an option. It is because the practical issue that caused my question does not involve languages like [Japanese or other East Asian languages where vertical writing is possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_and_vertical_writing_in_East_Asian_scripts). However if someone has information about graphs in those languages, and how the problem possibly differ compared to other languages, I'd be curious to hear about it (I guess that the option to write vertically simply gives more flexibility and makes things easier relative to vertical bar plots, but as I'm not familiar at all with those languages I may be wrong). A word or two about those languages might be also directly helpful to other people than me.

By the way, thanks to all the people who answered so far, it has been interesting and helpful.

Comment: Note that "vertical" and "horizontal" refers to the orientation of the *bars*. What SAS calls a "vertical" bar chart could easily be called a "horizontal" one, based on it being wider than tall, and categories arranged *horizontally*. Can you please edit this clarification into your question? Without it, this may be misunderstood majorly unless one clicks through to the SAS blog post.

Comment: I think this varies a bit by field.  But, with a small number of categories, I think it's just "this is what we're used to" along with "up is bigger" being, perhaps, a bit more intuitive than "to the right is bigger".

Comment: I took the freedom to edit the post and add a picture, feel free to revert (+1 by the way).

Comment: Because there are objective theories about the design and perception of quantitative graphics (see Bertin, Tufte, *et al.*), this is not necessarily an opinion-based question, so I have reopened it.

Comment: It is funny that very recently I looked into the *definition* to histogram and found out that it relates to Pearson who used the term and preferred the vertical over the horizontal. The 'hist' refers to 'mast' or upright posts. (I have no time to dig further into this but others might incorporate this into their answers)

Comment: In addition, while typically preferring vertical over horizontal, I like the horizontal case a lot in the case of a [population pyramid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_pyramid). Possibly this might be because of the symmetrical interpretation and it occurs in other cases of a binary comparison as well.

Comment: There is a false meme running that _histogram_ meant originally _history gram_ or some such. No!!!  The Greek root _histos_ is also used in histology.  The fashion to reach for Greek or Latin roots in coining new terms has faded.  Oddly enough, _scatter plot_ (originally _scatter diagram_) can also be traced to Karl Pearson. (Since  Egon Pearson was a major figure too, it's important to keep father and son distinct. In person, Karl could be awful, but Egon was much nicer, according to many stories.)

Comment: Population pyramids are over-rated. Subtle shifts in the ratio females to males, or its reciprocal, are important and common and expected but very hard to read off pyramids. (Bigger shifts are those you can spot easily.)

Comment: @NickCox Reading your discussion with SextusEmpiricus, what would be a good alternative to pyramid plots? Overlapping bars for men and women, with some transparency? Something else?

Comment: ... and now I'm wondering if I should ask a new question about that!

Comment: Plot male and female frequencies on the same axis as dots or lines. Log scale optional, but consistent with the idea that the ratio of either is of central interest.

Comment: I think that would be a fine question but check first that it hasn’t been asked already.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks. I didn't find a similar question, so I asked it here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/642714/alternatives-to-population-pyramids

Comment: The clear Answer is simply 'Yes, of course' and don't you see that as a query requiring lengthy teaching and long hours of practice at high-school level?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin No, as I got  interesting answers, very helpful to solve the practical problem I have described in the body text. From your comment (tell me if I misinterpreted it), I understand that you're annoyed because you find it would require a textbook to answer it, or that the question is too basic to be interesting to you. However no one forces you to answer it, and even if this question was high-school level, I wouldn't find anything wrong with asking about it. Everyone does not necessarily had the education you had access to. Hopefully this website is meant to correct this gap.

Comment: The issues may seem simple, even trivial, but at the same time people often do surprising things. I commonly see people, including experienced researchers, choosing poor graph designs and textbook writers, including those addressing beginners, giving bad advice or failing to give good advice.  I wouldn't simplify to saying that horizontal bar charts should be the default, but I often see vertical bar charts that really don't work well.

Comment: Thanks Coris. Please remember, no-one forced you to Ask that here, rather than doing some simple research of your own. 

Please note, if any combination of Answers or Comments here solved your problem, that was very likely more because of the triviality of the problem than anything else.

Look first at Stephan Kolassa's clear and simple Answer and explain, if you will, what part of that was not logically obvious?

Look at Nick Cox's Comment in the same light…

Explain, if you will, what part of that you could not have found through your own search engine before coming here?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Again, something obvious to you may not be obvious to other people. I didn't find anything relevant using search engines, if you want to know all the details. I think your comments are rude and ignorant of other people's educational background and circumstances. How am I supposed to know what I don't know and did not learn at school or elsewhere? Other people have been nice and helpful, so you certainly won't discourage me from using this website in the future if it's what you were hoping for.

Comment: Sorry, Coris  As this argument, discussion or what-you-call-it has no place here would you rather drop it, go to Chat or what?

I dismiss your claims because it's clear to anyone looking from what here in the UK, would be taught at about age 13-14, what at least some of the differences are.

If your searches found nothing, might different wording have been more helpful?

Nothing I said was rude.

Bad hands in education or circumstance are regrettable, yet offset by the ability to choose, collate and Post whatever…

Do you not realise, most 'educated' people could not do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have "many" categories, then a vertical chart will be wider than it is tall. A horizontal chart will be taller than it is wide. (Note the potential for confusion what "vertical" and "horizontal" mean, per [my comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/642485/are-there-situations-where-a-vertical-bar-chart-is-preferable-to-a-horizontal-on#comment1200613_642485).)

Which one makes more sense depends on your situation. Mobile phone screens are usually in portrait mode and would work better with horizontal charts. Laptops or desktop computer screens are usually in landscape orientation and may work better with vertical charts. If you are writing a paper, which one makes best use of your page real estate depends very much on the number of categories.

I would assume that humans are better at comparing the length of horizontal bars than the height of vertical ones, but do not know of any research on this. I am sure someone has already looked at this.

Comment: See William Cleveland's work.  As I recall, his studies did not find significant differences in perception of vertical vs. horizontal lengths.

Comment: @whuber, this is really interesting (came up recently), but I couldn't easily find where he did these comparisons. Can you point me to a paper or to page/chapter references in a book?

Comment: @BenBolker I'm wondering the same question . If whuber does not remember the reference, maybe that could be a new question,  in case someone else has this information?

Comment: @Ben William S. Cleveland (1985).  *The Elements of Graphing Data.*  See especially chapter 4, "Graphical Perception," and section 4.3, "Theory and Experimentation," summarizing Cleveland's work at Bell Labs. (I'm looking at the older first edition.) It's worth reading if only to understand the nuances of assessing graphical perception.  For a more comprehensive account, MacEachren's book will teach more than you ever wanted to know: MacEachren, Alan M. 2004. How Maps Work: Representation, Visualization, and Design. Guilford Press.

Comment: @Coris: pinging you about whuber's comment.

Comment: Hmm.  Looking at the *revised* edition on the Internet Archive [here](https://archive.org/details/elementsofgraphi0000clev), it doesn't look like this information is there (Chapter 4 doesn't seem to have anything at all about his experimental work). I would have to get the first edition by interlibrary loan ... I may ask another question (or @Coris might?) to get a summary of any experimental work on horizontal vs vertical layouts ...

Comment: @BenBolker Please be my guest, you've been the first to raise the question, and you may have additional elements to ask about I didn't think of.

Comment: Cleveland's work (collaborating with others) on perception of graphics was written up in major journals and should easily be accessible via jstor.org. I think his books are wonderful and hardly date  even after 30 years but they grow out of his work on perception, rather than discuss it in detail.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/642730/experimental-evidence-for-differences-in-perception-on-vertical-vs-horizontal-s

Comment: @NickCox, as explained in the question linked from the previous comment, I'm aware of Cleveland's work and have read several of his papers, but haven't managed to locate one that tested perception in horizontal vs vertical layouts (I do know, for example, about his experiments on aspect ratio and 45° banking ...)

Comment: I don’t recall any such comparison but it’s some time since I last read those papers.

Comment: @Ben I suspect there might not have been any experiments comparing vertical vs. horizontal lengths because the likely effect size is so small as to be (a) not worth measuring and (b) prohibitively expensive to measure.

Comment: @whuber, maybe. Given that there's lots of discussion of horizontal vs vertical layouts, I'd be curious. One of the papers I linked in my question uses Mechanical Turk. I wonder how much it would cost to get sufficient power for an effect size of (say) 10%?

Answer (score 23):

The accepted answer from @Stephan Kolassa is fine by me, but unsurprisingly more can be said.

First, let us clear out of the way a small question of definition. To some authors, bar charts are those with horizontal bars, while vertical bars define a column chart. If you think this distinction is somewhere between unnecessary and absurd, I agree with you. But it's far from dead, although I sense its use is declining. In what I see, the more common distinction is -- as in the question title -- between horizontal bar charts (bars go from left to right by default) and vertical bar charts (bars go from bottom to top by default). Neither term rules out (e.g.) pairing of bars, as in so-called population pyramids showing age distribution of population with bars for numbers of males and females laid back to back.

The leading point in my experience over whether to use horizontal or vertical bars is that **designers should show text labels legibly**, as mentioned in the question. All bar charts need clear explanations of the categories shown. This is usually easier with horizontal layout. With a vertical layout, some people use a legend instead of text by each bar. At best that is an awkward solution, as are some other work-arounds in common use, such as very small font sizes, text running at an angle (even vertically), or abbreviations verging on the cryptic. This comment, however, bites most, or even only, if text in the language used is customarily shown horizontally.

Conversely, some very concise abbreviations have become so widely accepted that they suit vertical bars, including chemical element symbols such as Cu and Zn and two-letter codes such as AL and AK for states of the United States.

Yet again, as @matt_black flags in his answer, some bar charts don't need labels for every bar, as is often true if bars are for a series of dates and mental interpolation is easy enough.

In addition, two points arise quite commonly.

In statistical graphics, vertical bars match a common convention that **whatever is the outcome or response of interest is usually plotted vertically** unless there is good reason to do otherwise.

Occasionally, **plotting vertically or horizontally may seem natural for other reasons, even if pure convention or just a matter of psychology**. Thus a bar chart for heights of buildings would seem very odd if presented horizontally, while durations (lengths of time) might seem better suited to horizontal layout.

Comment: +1, IMO "whatever is the outcome or response of interest is usually plotted vertically" is the main point: **convention**. Research would be much more painful if authors were randomly choosing axes for their independent and dependent variables.

Comment: @Sam Thanks for the upvote, but I don’t fully share your concern. In the Earth and environmental sciences, and in archaeology, height above or depth below the surface often are plotted vertically, even though it is usually not an outcome. People don’t seem much troubled by this different convention.

Comment: @Sam I'd say that convention is a bit weaker for bar charts which by their nature cannot have continuous bins. A graph often shows a function mapping an independent variable to a dependent one, and the non-redundancy of groups in a bar chart means you can always define a function mapping a bar to value, but not necessarily the other way around. I usually read the discrete bar categories as the independent variable whether they're on the x- or y-axis, since the continuous values are always mathematically a function of them.

Comment: @NickCox If the independent variable is literally "height", that is a more than reasonable justification for a change from convention. As are arguments about the medium, number of categories, etc. In my experience, if there is no strong argument for these exceptions, one is expected to present data in a format adhering closely to the formats of previous (especially cited) research in that field.

Answer (score 10):

One issue is to synchronize intuition with the convention of graphing mathematical functions with the dependent variable on the y-axis, and the independent variable on the x-axis (i.e., matching a vertical bar chart). For instance, if the data is quantitative, it's easier to eyeball whether it matches some known probability distribution previously studied. Here's an example from the Weiss *Introductory Statistics* textbook:

[image: Vertical bar chart with normal curve superimposed]

Comment: I don’t think the task would be harder if the axes were swapped. I have published papers with altitude histograms and so a vertical magnitude axis with no dissent from anyone evident.

Comment: Violin plots are popular visualizations that (typically) maps the shape of the distribution to y-axis instead of x-axis, as on your image. On the other hand, ridgeline does the opposite. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridgeline_plot

Comment: Violin plots or ridgelines don't in my experience show comparisons with theoretical or expected distributions, which is the point being made here, as I understand it.

Answer (score 3):

The conventional wisdom here is based on the readability of categorical labels which are often hard to read if the text is not horizontal.

But this can sometimes be unhelpful in context where the categories from part of a regular series. For example, if the plot is of monthly performance over several years. Here, not every bar needs to be labelled with the full name of the month as the reader of the chart knows the sequence of months and the reader can interpolate the *specific* months easily without the labels (eg when year boundaries are labelled). Plus, for data like time series, the common charts show them from left to right so the bars may be interpreted more naturally in that orientation.

So the penalty of *readability* for a chart oriented this way is not a notable issue.

Comment: Indeed. Sometimes time series are shown with bars and if there are many times and so many bars, then there is usually neither space nor need to label every time point. So agreed, but that said wouldn't a line chart work better in most circumstances? People often don't feel constrained by the difference between measurements at points and over intervals. However, your point is conditional on bar charts being the chosen method.

Comment: @NickCox The issue for using line charts over bar charts is subtle. Bar charts make it visually clear that the measurement is not continuous. Line charts hint to the user that measurements are. Whether this distinction matters is dependent on context. Sometimes,for example,  even when data could be measured daily it is only available in weekly or monthly aggregates.

Comment: I agree. Are you thinking I don't? Sorry if I am unclear.

Comment: @NickCox Not disagreeing, just clarifying the rationale.